# Present multiple dichoctomised variables in horizontal stacked bar chart

Tags: r, bar-chart, categorical-data

I have a couple of variables dichotomised as yes no. I'd like to present % or N of yes/no per variable in a bar chart like below. Haven't found a good description of how to do that. At least not when there are multiple variables involved. Any suggestions on how to go abut it?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data like this,

```
head(dat, 3)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
# 1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
# 2  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
# 3  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1
```

you easily could preprocess the data by using columns frequencies (`colSums`) and their inverse (subtracting from `nrow`). Next calculate `proportions`. Finally put it in `barplot` and apply some cosmetics.

```
## preprocess data
cs <- colSums(dat)
pdat <- proportions(rbind(nrow(dat) - cs, cs), margin=2)
# pdat <- rbind(nrow(dat) - cs, cs)  ## calculating N instead

## plot and output as .png
png('fooplot.png', 600, 400)  ## start .png device
op <- par(mar=c(5, 16, 5, 3)+.1)  ## set pars
b <- barplot(pdat, horiz=T, col=c(4, 2), names.arg=rep('', length(cs)), 
             main='Some title', legend.text=c('yes', 'no'), , 
             args.legend=list(x=.2, y=-1.5, bt='n', xpd=TRUE, horiz=T))
text(pdat[1, ]/2, b, paste0(pdat[1, ]*100, '%'), cex=.9)
text(pdat[1, ] + pdat[2, ]/2, b, paste0(pdat[2, ]*100, '%'), cex=.9)
# text(pdat[1, ]/2, b, pdat[1, ], cex=.9)  ## if calculating N
# text(pdat[1, ] + pdat[2, ]/2, b, pdat[2, ], cex=.9)  ## "
text(-.03, b, q, xpd=TRUE, adj=1)
par(op)  ## restore pars
dev.off()  ## stop .png device
```

[image]

Find the plot in your working directory `getwd()`.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- sapply(c(.3, .53, .29, .35, .39, .52, .31, .65, .68), \(x) rbinom(100, 1, x)) |>
  as.data.frame() 
q <- c('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?', 'Consectetur adipiscing elit?',
       'Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt?', 'Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?',
       'Donec et odio pellentesque diam?',  'Volutpat commodo sed. Quis risus?',
       'Sed vulputate odio ut enim blandit?', 'Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae?',
       'Elementum curabitur?')
```

Comment: That does look very nice, but in my case the variables are categorical. Seems like you have used numeric ones?

Comment: So mine looks like this:
#   V1  V2   V3   V4  V5  V6   V7   V8 V9
# Yes  Yes  No  Yes No  No  Yes  No  No  
# Yes  Yes  Yes  No  No  No  Yes  No  Yes

Comment: @StHe  Oh sorry, use `vars <- c('V1', 'V2', ...);dat[vars] <- lapply(dat[vars], \(x) ifelse(x == 'Yes', 1, 0))`.

Comment: @StHe Or less to type, `vars <- grep('^V', names(dat))`. Note that I use R >= 4.1, otherwise use `function(x)`instead of `\(x)` above in case, but always better update R.

Comment: @StHe Actually just changing `colSums(dat == 'Yes')` in answer should also be applicable to your data.